# Testing apps on Native Client ARM

Tags: google-nativeclient

I understand that there is no NaCl SDK support for ARM platform so far. I am right now developing applications for ARM on Ubuntu. Is there a way I can test the applications on ARM machines without using SDK?. As far as I understand from Native Client website, we need SDK to start the server to test the applications. Does any one have experience on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can develop your application on an x86 machine, and use the SDK's compilers to target NaCl ARM. This is commonly called cross-compiling. You then copy files over to the ARM machine that you want to test with, or use QEMU (to emulate ARM's ISA on an x86 machine).

It's possible to build a NaCl SDK from source for ARM, it's simply not distributed by the SDK team because there hasn't been demand for this.

You're trying to test in a browser? The server is there to serve content to a browser, but I've often found it simpler to use `python -m SimpleHTTPServer`.

Comment: Yeah, right now I am cross-compiling for ARM on my ubuntu x86-64 machine.  Sorry for the confusion.  Actually I need to debug it like a C application observing register contents etc.   Is there any documentation about how to build the SDK from the source?.  Thanks

Comment: https://www.chromium.org/nativeclient/how-tos/build-tcb and other pages on the wiki. In your case you just want to build the ARM version of GDB.

Comment: Can you please point me to the source code please?  I checked out from https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src.git/+/master/native_client_sdk/ .  This seems to be a Makefile based building, while your document says SCon based.

Comment: It's a bit more complicated that a single repo! Chrome contains the SDK build (the URL you point out), but the SDK build pulls in from other pre-built repos (detailed in the link I provide, and other parts of that wiki).

Comment: I tried to build that using the instructions given in BUILDING.rst.  I installed depot_tools including gclient. however, when I do "GYP_DEFINES=target_arch=arm gclient runhooks"  I get an error "Error: client not configured; see 'gclient config' "